# The size in KB / MB with only max. 2 digits after the comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, filesize

While uploading file size should display.

```
function File(name, size) {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = (size / 1024);
    this.url = null;
    this.isUploadCompleted = false;
    this.archiveStatus = null;
    this.progressBarObject = null;
    this.removeObject = null;
}
```

My present output `Size: 846.08203125KB`. My required output `size: 10.0KB`. What changes do I have to make in code?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: while uploading file size should display, it is displaying in above shown format, what changes i have to make in code?

Comment: Use `.toFixed(2)` number method. `this.size = (size / 1024).toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`toFixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) function to convert a number into a string and decide how many decimals keep.

In your case, if you want to show `2` decimals:

```
this.size = (size / 1024).toFixed(2);
```